# CAs,Enrollment,Registration for HyperLedger Fabric for multi-organizational.

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I'm trying to establish the multichannel network with 3 Org and 3 CA server of each organisation and there is only one peer in each organisation & there is two channel, first is in between Org1---Org2 and second is in between Org1---Org3. I'm facing problem at enrollment via node sdk. i just enrolled 1 admin & register 1 user for each organization with their MSP ids.. but for org1 only i can able to do it and for rest of other organization its giving error.Please can any one share there knowledge on this where actually i'm doing mistake.

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.3/fabcar

something like enrollAdmin.js & registerUser.js
I'm trying..

```
version: '2'

networks:
      basic:

services:
  ca.org1.example.com:
   image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
   environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ee2d84ed07a905e1da7e37720d8ab19e10955a7de00c37f80ee5003da2fe71fb_sk
ports:
  - "7054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca.org1.example.com
networks:
  - basic

ca.org2.example.com:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org2.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/8672a5680bfc1549c80a2bd51ebf5f9377963842bc69c953beff22b5fa7fd4a1_sk
ports:
  - "8054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca.org2.example.com
networks:
  - basic

ca.org3.example.com:
image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
environment:
  - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org3.example.com
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem
  - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/7fae57bfc762f669eed6f05a6dbe1d1284366a7cf23e2060c38501360c90405c_sk
ports:
  - "9054:7054"
command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
volumes:
  - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
container_name: ca.org3.example.com
networks:
  - basic


orderer.example.com:
container_name: orderer.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
environment:
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/etc/hyperledger/configtx/genesis.block
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
  - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer/msp
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
command: orderer
ports:
  - 7050:7050
volumes:
    - ./config/:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/orderer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg1
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg2
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peerOrg3
networks:
  - basic

peer0.org1.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # # bridge network as the peers
  # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
  # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
  # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
# command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
ports:
  - 7051:7051
  - 7053:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - couchdb
networks:
  - basic

peer0.org2.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
  # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # # bridge network as the peers
  # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
  # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
  # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
# command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
ports:
  - 8051:7051
  - 8053:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - couchdb
networks:
  - basic

peer0.org3.example.com:
container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
image: hyperledger/fabric-peer
environment:
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.example.com
  - CORE_LOGGING_PEER=debug
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer/
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
  # # the following setting starts chaincode containers on the same
  # # bridge network as the peers
  # # https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/
  - CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE=${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}_basic
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb:5984
  # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
  # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
  # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
  - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
command: peer node start
# command: peer node start --peer-chaincodedev=true
ports:
  - 9051:7051
  - 9053:7053
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/msp/peer
    - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/users:/etc/hyperledger/msp/users
    - ./config:/etc/hyperledger/configtx
depends_on:
  - orderer.example.com
  - couchdb
networks:
  - basic


couchdb:
container_name: couchdb
image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
# Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
# for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
environment:
  - COUCHDB_USER=
  - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
ports:
  - 5984:5984
networks:
  - basic


cli:
container_name: cli
image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
tty: true
environment:
  - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
  - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
  - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
  - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
  - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
  - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
  - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
  - CORE_CHAINCODE_KEEPALIVE=10
working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
command: /bin/bash
volumes:
    - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
    - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/
    - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
    - ./config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifaexample
networks:
    - basic

#depends_on:
#  - orderer.example.com
#  - peer0.org1.example.com
#  - peer0.org2.example.com
#  - peer0.org3.example.com
#  - couchdb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, You have misunderstood concept.

In reality, NodeSDK is part of client, At a time one client application can represent one Organization.

However; If you are trying to create users for each organization, You need to make sure to send request to each different CA with different input parameter for each organization.

Comment: okay.. I got something on this topic please have a look https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-network-config.html.